What I am doing wrong in the below code(logic) debugging Code for handling in User?
I need to handle Privacy Policy and Terms & Conditions Versions for User Authentication.
I have added below code, where I want to check if the current user is new user or existing user.  If the user is new then he should not get any pop up and and i am checking the same that he will not having any data in localstorage. And for existing or already logged in user who accepted both PP , TnC that are stored in locastorage and now the case is there are updates for PP and/or TnC, so that the user gets a pop up to accept it.
I am showing the pop ups regarding updated PP / TnC in below code if the user is already accepted it earlier. But the problem here is even the new user is getting the pop up. What i am doing wrong here?
const lastPPVersion: number = parseFloat(localStorage.get("LAST_ACCEPTED_PP_VERSION"));
const lastTNCVersion: number = parseFloat(localStorage.get("LAST_ACCEPTED_TC_VERSION"));

const currentPPVersion = UserInfo.privacyLatestVersion;
const currentTNCVersion = UserInfo.termsLatestVersion;

const acceptedLatestPP = !isNaN(lastPPVersion) && lastPPVersion == currentPPVersion;
const acceptedLatestTC = !isNaN(lastTNCVersion) && lastTNCVersion == currentTNCVersion;

// check if not new user
if (!isNaN(lastPPVersion) && !isNaN(lastTNCVersion)) {

    if (!acceptedLatestPP && !acceptedLatestTC) {
        //handle for both PP and TC update 
        //add pop up saying Both PP TNC updated
        localStorage.set("LAST_ACCEPTED_PP_VERSION",`${currentPPVersion}`);
        localStorage.set("LAST_ACCEPTED_TC_VERSION",`${currentTNCVersion}`);

    }

    else if (!acceptedLatestPP || !acceptedLatestTC) {

        if (!acceptedLatestPP) {
            //handle for PP update
            //add pop up saying PP updated
            localStorage.set("LAST_ACCEPTED_PP_VERSION",`${currentPPVersion}`);

        }
        else {
            //handle for TC update
            //add pop up saying TNC updated
            localStorage.set("LAST_ACCEPTED_TC_VERSION",`${currentTNCVersion}`);
        }
    }
} 

Please check the above code and confirm whether it meets the requirement.?
When a user logs in and accepts the privacy policy (PP) and terms and conditions (TC), the lastPPVersion and lastTNCVersion are stored in localStorage.
These versions represent the latest accepted versions at the time of user acceptance.
For both newly logged-in and existing users. I am sure that currentPPVersion and currentTNCVersion fetched from the server is correct and would represent the latest versions available.
Additionally, isNaN should be used to differentiate between newly logged-in and existing users based on the localStorage storage."
I checked in all files if I am changing the storage any where, and I am clearing the storage if the user logged out of any account. What mistake is i am doing here?
Thank you for understanding this.
